# String error with replacingOccurrences

Tags: swift

For the following Swift 3 code:

```
var password = "Mary had a little lamp"
var newPassword = password.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "A")
```

I get this error on the call to `replacingOccurrences`:

> value of type 'String' has no member 'replacingOccurrences'

Comment: You need to specify the swift version that you are currently using?

Comment: `replacingOccurrences(of` is valid in Swift 3.

Comment: yes its Swift 3

Comment: Did you `import Foundation`?

Comment: If you are running this in playground, as @Hamish mentioned, you need to add `import Foundation`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, working in swift3

```
var newPassword = password.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "A", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
```

Comment: getting this msg:  ------------------------------------------
| THERE WERE ISSUES RUNNING YOUR CODE... |
------------------------------------------
StudentMain.swift:4:79: error: use of unresolved identifier 'NSString'
var newPassword = password.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "A" , options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
                                                                              ^~~~~~~~
Swift.String:268:15: note: did you mean 'String'?
public struct String {
              ^

Answer (score 1):

var newPassword = password.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "A", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)

Those having problems with unresolved identifier 'NSString', remember to import Foundation.